# Is there an automated way to convert a scene's Cycles materials into Blender Internal materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, .fbx

I'm working with Cycles, preparing a scene with many objects to export it as fbx to Unreal Engine 4, I unwrapped and baked all textures, named all objects, textures, and materials properly.
The problem is, when I import the fbx file in UE4, textures are not linked properly to the materials, I need to import all textures, link them one by one to each material, it's a painful process.
I know that this process using BI is a piece of cake, is there a way, an addon or a script that makes materials and textures well embedded in fbx using Cycles materials? Am I missing something, a checkbox that I need to enable maybe?
In case that is not possible in Cycles, is there a way to convert Cycles materials to Blender Internal materials without having to go through the whole process of linking manually all broken textures links?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the question is related indeed, but the answer doesn't answer my question, I tried exporting fbx using blender internal material, it worked as expected, the textures in UE4 were linked properly, I didn't need to touch the material in UE4, this is not the case for Cycles. A friend of mine is using C4D and it worked for him too, my question is, is there a workaround that will make it work in blender? whether an addon, or a way to convert Cycles material to Blender Internal material.

Comment: For instance, in 3D Max, if you're working with VRay, you can right click in the view port and choose an operation to convert all scene material to VRay material, I need to know if there's something similar for Cycles in Blender.

Comment: It all boils down to how the exporter was written, Blender's exporter was made with Internal render in mind only apparently. You can search this site for for questions about material conversion with good answers. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=convert+cycles+materials+

Comment: I went through many answers, I even found an addon that converts from BI to Cycles, but not the other way around, looks like the only solution is to start learning BI, thanks for the help @DuarteFarrajotaRamos