# Is there a way to port all your Cycles Render materials to Blender Render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I made an object in Cycles Render and I have created and assigned my own materials to the object. I have just realised that a game engine is not compatible with Cycles Render and is only compatible with Blender Render, so when I switched to Blender Render this is what I see in the material's inspecter. Is there a way to port all these materials to Blender Render?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Materials from Cycles to Blender Internal Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render)

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77449/is-there-an-automated-way-to-convert-a-scenes-cycles-materials-into-blender-int